# What is this series of Warhammer Fantasy Roleplay adventures where the goal of each was to get an elemental gem of power?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, published-adventures, product-identification, wfrp-2e, wfrp-1e

Many years ago (24+), I had a set of 4 *Warhammer Fantasy Roleplay* adventures split between 2 books.

Each adventure's goal was to try and claim an elemental gem of power. The gems were tremendously powerful, and when combined and at the end of the adventure, it was suggested the world ended.

At the time, I remember being told the adventure had been converted from a famous published D&D campaign.

I am trying to remember both the name of the WFRP adventure and the D&D campaign it may have been based on.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### You are almost certainly remembering the Doomstones campaign.

See the BoardGameGeek page on the [Doomstones Campaign](https://www.boardgamegeek.com/wiki/page/family:297) for WFRP for more details; the campaign was first published by Flame Publications in 1990, and republished by Hogshead Publishing in 1996. The page states:

> When the campaign was re-published by Hogshead Publishing, they published two volumes with two adventures each:
>
> Doomstones Campaign Volume 1 - *Fire and Blood*
> Doomstones Campaign Volume 2 *- Wars & Death*

According to the BoardGameGeek page on [*The Complete Dungeon Master Series*](https://boardgamegeek.com/wiki/page/family:1238) (which was first published by Beast Enterprises from 1984 through 1986), that series - which included rules for playing the adventures using D&D - was later reworked into the Doomstones Campaign.